# Why is the initialization in the constructor -1 instead of other numbers like 0? implementing two stacks in an array

Tags: java

I am looking at an example code of implementing two stacks in an array. There is a part in the initialization that I don't understand. Why initialize top1 as -1 instead of 0; and why top2 as size instead of size-1?

Here is the code:

```
public class StackArray {
    int size;
    int top1, top2;
    int arr[];

    public StackArray(int n){
        size = n;
        arr = new int[n];
        top1 = -1;
        top2 = size;
    }
    public void push1(int x){
        if(top1<top2-1){
        top1++;
        arr[top1] = x;

        }

        else{
            System.out.println("There is a stack overflow ");
        }
    }

    public void push2(int x){
        if (top1<top2-1){
            top2--;
            arr[top2] = x;


        }
        else{
            System.out.println("There is a stackoverflow");
        }
    }

    public int pop1(){
        if(top1>=0){
            int x = arr[top1];
            top1--;
            return x;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(size);
            System.out.println("There is a stack underflow");
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int pop2(){
        if (top2<size){
            int x = arr[top2];
            top2++;
            return x;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("There is a stack underflow");
        }
        return -1;
    }



}
```

Comment: Write a test; then change the numbers and see what behaviour changes.

Comment: my suggestion would be to change the value to `0` and then debug it and see what happens

Comment: BTW, the `toString()` method almost certainly doesn't do what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this class implements two stacks implemented by pushing elements to the two ends of the array.

When the constructor is called, the stacks are empty, so it makes sense for the heads of the 2 stacks to point to indices just outside the valid range of the array - -1 in one end and the array's length (`arr.length`) in the other end.

When you push the first element to the first stack (`push1`), `top1` is incremented to 0 and the element in added to the first index of the array.

When you push the first element to the second stack (`push2`), `top2` is decremented to `arr.length - 1` and the element is added to the last index of the array.

For example, suppose the array's length is 7.

At first, when the stacks are empty, `head1` and `head2` point to locations just outside the array :

```
    ------------------------------------
    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    ------------------------------------
 -1   0    1    2    3    4    5    6     7
head1                                   head2
```

When calling `push1(5)`, `head1` is incremented :

```
    ------------------------------------
    | 5  |    |    |    |    |    |    |
    ------------------------------------
 -1   0    1    2    3    4    5    6     7
    head1                               head2
```

After calling `push2(34)`, `head2` is decremented :

```
    ------------------------------------
    | 5  |    |    |    |    |    | 34 |
    ------------------------------------
 -1   0    1    2    3    4    5    6     7
    head1                         head2
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `0` and `size-1` are *valid* index values of the stack.
Since your stack is initialized empty, then the values for the start and end indexes are initialized as *out of bounds*.

This way, the first push to the start of the stack takes `top1` to index `0` (the actual start of the array) and the first push to the end of the stack takes `top2` to index `size-1` (the actual end of the array)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StackArray {

    int size;

    int top1, top2;

    int arr[];

    public MainJava(int n) {
        size = n;
        arr = new int[n];
        top1 = -1;
        top2 = size;
    }

    public void push1(int x) {
        if (top1 < top2 - 1) {
            top1++;
            arr[top1] = x;

        }

        else {
            System.out.println("There is a stack1 overflow ");
        }
    }

    public void push2(int x) {
        if (top1 < top2 - 1) {
            top2--;
            arr[top2] = x;

        } else {
            System.out.println("There is a stack2 overflow");
        }
    }

    public int pop1() {
        if (top1 >= 0) {
            int x = arr[top1];
            arr[top1] = 0;
            top1--;
            return x;
        } else {
            System.out.println(size);
            System.out.println("There is a stack1 underflow");
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int pop2() {
        if (top2 < size) {
            int x = arr[top2];
            arr[top2] = 0;
            top2++;
            return x;
        } else {
            System.out.println("There is a stack2 underflow");
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("The array is : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            result.append(arr[i] + "\t");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

}
```

Reason for top1 size keeping at -1 is when you pop1 all records one by one to catch stack underflow -1 is clean option. Array index start from 0.
Also top2 is kept as size (and not as size -1) because if no item is pushed in stack 2 and you try to pop it. It should work properly.

So basically it is kept at those values considering worst case scenarios.

Modified toString to print records properly.

Cheers !!!